# why public abstract method socket createSocket exists in a specific class

Tags: java, sockets

Recently, I'm learning `SSL` in `Java` and saw a method:

```
public abstract Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException
```

in `SSLSocketFactory` class.

Why the modifier "`abstract`" in `createSocket` method exists in `SSLSocketFactory`, which is not an abstract class. Since it's an `abstract` method in `SSLSocketFactory`, it means it hasn't been implemented right?

Comment: Unless you're thinking of a different [`SSLSocketFactory`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/net/SocketFactory.java#SocketFactory.createSocket%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29) class, [it is abstract](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.java#SSLSocketFactory).

Comment: Java requires classes that have abstract methods to be abstract. SSLSocketFactory is an abstract class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html